# How to send Apple Pay token to Stripe?

Tags: php, web, stripe-payments, applepayjs

I am developing a website where each user can connect their Stripe account and sell own products. Adding the domain into Stripe account is not a solution, because 1 website and multiple Stripe accounts.

My task is to integrate Apple Pay Web JS.

At this moment I added the button, then when user clicks on it I am validating the session. Then on `onpaymentauthorized` I am receiving the next data:

```
{
  "token":{
    "paymentData":{
      "data":"...",
      "signature":"...",
      "header":{"publicKeyHash":"...","ephemeralPublicKey":"...","transactionId":"..."},
      "version":"EC_v1"
    },
    "paymentMethod":{
      "displayName":"Visa 1234",
      "network":"Visa",
      "type":"debit"
    },
    "transactionIdentifier":"..."
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell/show me how to send this data to Stripe? I unfortunately can not find a documentation. All documentations say about domain verification on Stripe dashboard.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There's no documented way to do this.  I recommend reaching out to [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/contact/email) to ask them if this is possible.